# Figuring out how to replace data with Disk in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a sorting app with XCode, and am struggling to figure out how to store data inside a pre-existing json file.

Sample JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id":1001,
        "trackName":"Rain of Amethyst",
        "intensity":0,
        "album":"crystallized"
    },
    {
        "id":1002,
        "trackName":"Artificial Snow",
        "intensity":0,
        "album":"crystallized"
    },
    ...
]
```

`.swift` File:

```
import SwiftUI
import Disk

struct TrackRow: View {
    var track: Track
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(track.album)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(track.trackName)
                Text(track.album)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(String(track.intensity))
                .padding(.trailing)
                .onTapGesture {
                    //Block of code here that somehow edits JSON data
                }
        }
    }
}
...
```

How do I replace the `intensity` value with a different integer?

I've searched through different documentations and implementations, and none of them seemed to work, although I admit as a novice, I may be looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: You can't write to a file in your bundle. But, you can write to a JSON file elsewhere in the filesystem, like the documents directory, for example. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/writing-data-to-the-documents-directory for example

Comment: @jnpdx So there's no way at all I can store data permanently? I know from Apple's SwiftUI tutorial that I was able to change data, but it differed from build to build. Was that technically storing data?

Comment: I didn't say anything about not being able to store data permanently. I just said you can't write to a file in your bundle. In terms of permanence, there's nothing you can do to prevent a user from deleting a file, an app, or clearing the contents of their phone.

Comment: I understand now. Now that I have that figured, I still need to find out how to replace the `intensity` value.

Comment: To have mutable data, you may want to learn about `@State`

Comment: The most straightforward way to handle it is to model the JSON data with a Codable struct. You then use the struct in your file where you need the data, and update the struct (see mutating struct), and then encode the struct to data, and write the data to the disk. So it is a 2 step process encoding and decoding data as needed, and read or write data from disk. These processes are handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

As jnpdx mentioned, you can't write JSON directly in bundle.

However [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) may help you permanently save data as you desire. This solution is a little complex if you are not familiar with `CoreData`, but it provides you with a structured data structure.

1. Parse your JSON file and save the result to `CoreData`.

```swift
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let result = try decoder.decode([Track].self, from: data)
        // CoreData insert
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
       
    struct Track: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var trackName: String
        var intensity: Int
        var album: String
    }
```

2. Copy the .sqlite file in app to your project directory.

   (Do steps 1, 2 only if you update your JSON file content)
   Download the container first. The .sqlite may exist in `AppData/Documents` folder.
   [image]
3. Fetch the records you want and then update `intensity's` value in `CoreData`. 
   Some reference: [CoreData fetch(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506672-fetch), [CoreData insert(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506794-insert) with [NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergebypropertyobjecttrumpmergepolicy)

---

Alternatively, You can try Plan B:

Copy the JSON file to `Documents directory` when the user launches your app for the first time. Always read/write the file in the 'Documents' directory.

1. In `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` check the JSON exists in `Documents directory`. Skip step 2 if it already exists.
2. Use `FileManager.default.copyItem()` to copy file to `Documents directory`.
3. Parse your JSON file in `Documents directory`.
4. Modify `intensity` as per the `Track` model you defined.
5. Save it back to JSON file in `Documents directory`.

### Conclusion

`CoreData` is **highly recommended** when you need to deal with a large JSON file. **As a good app, we often use CoreData to help us manage the database in our mobile devices.** It has better performance.

On the other hand, `Plan B` is only suitable when your JSON size is very small because it requires reading/writing the entire JSON file every time.

[Note] It's a bit challenging to explain clearly. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.